# How to set permanent placeholder for selectfield in sencha touch 2 even after selecting the record

Tags: sencha-touch

It always appears as default like this: `-----selection-----`.

Even after selecting `selectfield` it remains same.

My code:

```
xtype: 'selectfield',
    id:'selMyGroupNames',
    left:'1%',
    top : '14%',
    width:'38%',
    label : 'My Groups:',
    store:'MyGroupNames',
    valueField:'fid',
    displayField:'name',
    autoSelect:false,
    labelWidth:'45%',
    style: {
        background:'#576870',
        fontSize :'16px'
    },
    placeHolder:'- - - New - - -'
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code.

First it will display `-----selection-----` in placeHolder.

If you select first option, placeHolder remains the same. It's bug and fixed in senchaTouch 2.3

[See here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?266525-Select-field-first-option-cannot-select-with-Placeholder)

If you select any option other than first, everything works good.